# ifconfig showing eth0 when using wifi

Tags: linux, networking, terminal, ifconfig

I'm using Ubuntu through WSL. When running the `ifconfig`, I get back two blocks; one for `eth0` and one for `lo`. However, it is my understanding that `eth0` is only for when you are connected to the internet via an ethernet cable, and yet I am using wifi and do not have a `wlan0` block.

Can someone please explain why this would be the case?

My wifi box is connected via an ethernet cable, but it was my (perhaps mistaken) understanding that `eth0` was only for when you had an ethernet cable plugged directly into your machine. If this is the case, is `wlan0` only for when your wifi router is also wireless?

Answer (score 0):

Because windows isn't exposing the physical device to WSL. You'll see similar behaviour with virtualisation platforms like VMware desktop or VirtualBox.